# Programa en C++ dejó de funcionar

Tags: c++, matrices, punteros

Estoy trabajando con matrices dinámicas, punteros y funciones. El ejercicio que tengo que hacer es el siguiente:

> Realizar la suma de dos matrices dinamicas y mostrar su resultado.

Básicamente no encuentro el error ya que el programa ejecuta correctamente pero a la hora de ingresar los valres para la matriz 1 el programa se tilda y muestra un mensaje dejó de funcionar. Les dejo el codigo para que lo puedan ver.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//Funciones

void pedir_Datos();
void sumar_Datos(int **,int **,int,int);
void mostrar_Datos(int **,int **,int,int);

//Variables globales

int **dir_Matriz1,**dir_Matriz2;
int N_filas = 0,N_columnas = 0;

int main(){
    //LLamada a las funciones

    pedir_Datos();
    sumar_Datos(dir_Matriz1,dir_Matriz2,N_filas,N_columnas);    
    mostrar_Datos(dir_Matriz1,dir_Matriz2,N_filas,N_columnas);

    //Eliminando / liberando memoria asignada

    //Eliminando memoria en filas
    for(int i = 0; i<N_filas; i++){
        delete[] dir_Matriz1[i];
    }

    //Eliminando memoria en columnas
    delete[] dir_Matriz1;


    //Eliminando memoria en filas
    for(int i = 0; i<N_filas; i++){
        delete[] dir_Matriz2[i];
    }

    //Eliminando memoria en columnas
    delete[] dir_Matriz2;

    getch();
    return 0;
}

//Definiciones de funciones

void pedir_Datos(){
    cout<<"Matriz A : "<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;

    cout<<"Numero de filas : ";
    cin>>N_filas;

    cout<<"Numero de columnas : ";
    cin>>N_columnas;

    cout<<" "<<endl;    

    //Asignando memoria en filas
    dir_Matriz1 = new int*[N_filas];
    //Asignando memoria en columnas
    for(int i = 0; i<N_columnas; i++){
        dir_Matriz1 = new int*[N_columnas];
    }

    //Elementos de la matriz 1

    for(int i = 0; i<N_filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<N_columnas; j++){
            cout<<(j+1)<<". Matriz : ";
            cin>>*(*(dir_Matriz1+i)+j);
        }
        cout<<" "<<endl;
    }
    cout<<" "<<endl;

    cout<<"Matriz B : "<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;

    cout<<"Numero de filas : ";
    cin>>N_filas;

    cout<<"Numero de columnas : ";
    cin>>N_columnas;

    //Asignando memoria en filas
    dir_Matriz2 = new int*[N_filas];
    //Asignando memoria en columnas
    for(int i = 0; i<N_columnas; i++){
        dir_Matriz2 = new int*[N_columnas];
    }

    cout<<" "<<endl;    

    //Elementos de la matriz 2

    for(int i = 0; i<N_filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<N_columnas; j++){
            cout<<(j+1)<<". Matriz : ";
            cin>>*(*(dir_Matriz2+i)+j);
        }
        cout<<" "<<endl;
    }
    cout<<" "<<endl;
}

void sumar_Datos(int **dir_Matriz1,int **dir_Matriz2,int N_filas,int N_columnas){
    for(int i = 0; i<N_filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<N_columnas; j++){
            *(*(dir_Matriz1+i)+j) = *(*(dir_Matriz1+i)+j) + *(*(dir_Matriz2+i)+j);
        }
    }
}

void mostrar_Datos(int **dir_Matriz1,int **dir_Matriz2,int N_filas,int N_columnas){
    for(int i = 0; i<N_filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<N_columnas; j++){
            cout<<*(*(dir_Matriz1+i)+j);
        }
        cout<<" "<<endl;
    }
    cout<<" "<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Si para sumar dos matrices ambas deben tener las mismas dimensiones, entonces, ¿Por qué pides las dimensiones dos veces?

```
cout<<"Matriz A : "<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;

cout<<"Numero de filas : ";
cin>>N_filas;

cout<<"Numero de columnas : ";
cin>>N_columnas;

// ...

cout<<"Matriz B : "<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;

cout<<"Numero de filas : ";
cin>>N_filas;

cout<<"Numero de columnas : ";
cin>>N_columnas;
```

Si el usuario se confunde y cambia las dimensiones habrás perdido las dimensiones de la primera matriz, luego el fracaso estará asegurado. Mejor pide las dimensiones una sola vez.

Por otro lado la reserva de memoria está mal hecha:

```
//Asignando memoria en filas
dir_Matriz1 = new int*[N_filas];
//Asignando memoria en columnas
for(int i = 0; i<N_columnas; i++){
    dir_Matriz1 = new int*[N_columnas];
}
```

En primer lugar, la primera reserva debería ser de tipo `int**`, pero bueno, el resultado final va a ser el mismo aunque convendría corregirlo. Por otro lado fíjate que **todas** las reservas se asignan a `dir_matriz1`, cuando la reserva de las columnas debería ir en `dir_matriz1[i]`:

```
//Asignando memoria en filas
dir_Matriz1 = new int**[N_filas];
//Asignando memoria en columnas
for(int i = 0; i<N_columnas; i++){
    dir_Matriz1[i] = new int*[N_columnas];
    //         ^^^ IMPORTANTE!!!
}
```

Y lo mismo para la segunda matriz.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pense que esta bien lo que hacia! saludos

Comment: De nada, @LionelRomero . Si la respueta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada.